# Update Manager shows '2 updates have been selected' when there are no updates

Tags: updates

The Update Manager is showing '2 updates have been selected' and that 4.1mb will be downloaded.

In the info box, no updates are shown.

When I click 'Install Updates', the installing updates box opens and closes immediately and  it shows the progress bar as it shows after it's done refreshing the sources.

[image: update manager]

I did 'sudo apt-get upgrade' in the terminal and it shows that no updates are available.
What's the deal?

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Comment: This may be a bug,  but I'll have to check...

Comment: I didn't see a bug report so I submitted a bug report here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-manager/+bug/1035696

Comment: If it's not considered a bug, we may continue here...

Comment: @ObsessiveFOSS Well, do you have an answer?

Comment: No, sorry. I'm still looking, but I'll publicize in chat...

Answer (score 2):

I did some searching in Synaptic for packages that I had locked, and I found that two packages I had locked and forced the version of, so I unlocked those packages and now it doesn't show that '2 packages have been selected' anymore.
Still, I think this is a bug.